# reloading a div with onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a memory game with a timer made of heavy jquery. I also have a button that reloads the memory game. The timer is called by a single div. I just want a simple function that reloads my "div" timer when you click the button that resets the game.

The code is too much to display, but here is the html that shows the countdown div. I just want my button to reload the div.

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="countdown"></div>
     <table id="gameBoard">
       <tbody>                  
       </tbody>
     </table>
     <button id="playAgain">Restart Game</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Samitha, I just want to reload a single div. Here is the game - http://jsfiddle.net/Brannan2/VkKRa/1/, this is the game, and here is the code for the timer that is added above the game

```
(function($){

    var days    = 24*60*60,
        hours   = 60*60,
        minutes = 60;

    $.fn.countup = function(prop){

        var options = $.extend({
            callback    : function(){},
            start       : new Date()
        },prop);

        var passed = 0, d, h, m, s, 
            positions;

    init(this, options);

        positions = this.find('.position');

        (function tick(){

            passed = Math.floor((new Date() - options.start) / 1000);


            d = Math.floor(passed / days);
            updateDuo(0, 1, d);
            passed -= d*days;


            h = Math.floor(passed / hours);
            updateDuo(2, 3, h);
            passed -= h*hours;


            m = Math.floor(passed / minutes);
            updateDuo(4, 5, m);
            passed -= m*minutes;


            s = passed;
            updateDuo(6, 7, s);


            options.callback(d, h, m, s);


            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        })();


        function updateDuo(minor,major,value){
            switchDigit(positions.eq(minor),Math.floor(value/10)%10);
            switchDigit(positions.eq(major),value%10);
        }

        return this;
    };


    function init(elem, options){
        elem.addClass('countDownHolder');


        $.each(['Days','Hours','Minutes','Seconds'],function(i){
            $('<span class="count'+this+'">').html(
                '<span class="position">\
                    <span class="digit static">0</span>\
                </span>\
                <span class="position">\
                    <span class="digit static">0</span>\
                </span>'
            ).appendTo(elem);

            if(this!="Seconds"){
                elem.append('<span class="countDiv countDiv'+i+'"></span>');
            }
        });

    }

    function switchDigit(position,number){

        var digit = position.find('.digit')

        if(digit.is(':animated')){
            return false;
        }

        if(position.data('digit') == number){
            return false;
        }

        position.data('digit', number);

        var replacement = $('<span>',{
            'class':'digit',
            css:{
                top:'-2.1em',
                opacity:0
            },
            html:number
        });


        digit
            .before(replacement)
            .removeClass('static')
            .animate({top:'2.5em',opacity:0},'fast',function(){
                digit.remove();
            })

        replacement
            .delay(100)
            .animate({top:0,opacity:1},'fast',function(){
                replacement.addClass('static');
            });
    }
})(jQuery);                       css - .countDownHolder{
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font: 40px/1.5 'Open Sans Condensed',sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:-3px;
}

.position{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1.6em;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.05em;
}

.digit{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:1em;
    background-color:#444;
    border-radius:0.2em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
}

.digit.static{
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.35);

    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #3A3A3A 50%, #444444 50%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #3A3A3A 50%, #444444 50%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #3A3A3A 50%, #444444 50%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #3A3A3A 50%, #444444 50%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #3A3A3A 50%, #444444 50%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.5, #3A3A3A),
        color-stop(0.5, #444444)
    );
}


.countDiv0{}
.countDiv1{}
.countMinutes{}
.countDiv2{}
.countSeconds{}


.countDiv{
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:1.6em;
    position:relative;
}

.countDiv:before,
.countDiv:after{
    position:absolute;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    background-color:#444;
    border-radius:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-3px;
    top:0.5em;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.5);
    content:'';
}

.countDiv:after{
    top:0.9em;
}
```

Comment: do you want to reload the DIV only or entire page ?

Comment: _"The code is too much to display"_. So just post the relevant parts.

Comment: I added the jfiddle for the game and reedited my original question with the code of the timer. The timer is loaded with the "countdown" div. How do I make my button reset my timer?

Comment: @2Truth (After seeing you edit an answer twice) Do not edit someone's answer to ask them something. Use the comment section if you want to ask something. Remember that you can the developer console to debug *why* something is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, first you need a timer right? Then you can worry about the wrapper, so, let's set a timer:

**JavaScript**

```
// Refresh Timer
function refreshTimer() {
    // Set counter
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Get timer value and decrement in 1
        var myTime = parseInt( $('.timer').html() ) - 1;
        // If timer has not reached 0
        if( myTime > 0 ) {
            // Set timer
            $('.timer').html( myTime );
        } else {
            // Else do something
            $('.timer').html('Time up!');
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

Then let's execute the timer when someone starts the game, and listen to reset clicks:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Alloted time in seconds
    var timeVal = 100;
    // Set timer
    $('.timer').html( timeVal );
    // Load timer function
    refreshTimer();
    // Refresh button
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        // Reset timer
        $('.timer').html( timeVal );
        // Clear interval
        clearInterval( loadTimer );
        // Load interval again
        loadTimer = setInterval( refreshTimer, timerInterval );
        // Set timer
        refreshTimer();
    });
    // Interval
    var timerInterval = 1000;
    var loadTimer = setInterval(refreshTimer, timerInterval);
});
```

As you can see, ***.btn*** is where timer is being reset and executed again, so those functions should be placed within your **$("#playAgain")** function.

jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/qKYHs/

Comment: I'm glad it works as expected. There are some tweaks to do in order to implement this solution in your game, for those looking for the whole implementation I've tweaked your code including this solution, here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/VkKRa/2/. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an ajax call that returns the div's updated content in the response and then use `$('#content').html(response)` to load the response into the div.

If that's not what you meant, please elaborate what you meant by "reload the div" and provide some of your js code.

Comment: Samitha, I just want to reload a single div. Here is the game - http://jsfiddle.net/Brannan2/VkKRa/1/, this is the game, and here is the code for the timer that is added above the game.. I edited my original answer with a jfiddle of the game and the code that adds the timer

Comment: What isn't working as you expect? To me it looks like it refreshes (the cards are different and all are face-down) when clicking the "play again" button.

Comment: Mayabelle, check my original question with the code that adds the timer. I need the countdown div to refresh "reset the timer" when you click the "restart game" button

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the timer a name instead of putting it to an anonymous function.

```
var timer;

timer = function($){ 
  var days    = 24*60*60,
  // other codes
}
```

Then, call the timer on page init. Put it here:

```
var shuffledCards = [];
var cardToMatchElement;

setupGame();
timer();
```

Then, call the timer again when clicking the reset button:

```
$("#playAgain").click(function() {
    setupGame();
    timer();
});
```